# CCNA No Longer Required?

Tags: cisco

Is it true that anyone can go straight and take the CCNP exams (Switch, Route & TShoot) now without passing CCNA first?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need CCNA first, but you need to give two exams: The core exam and concentration exam in order to become CCNP. Have a look at this link for what is required for each Cisco certification: [Cisco cert career path](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/training-events/certifications/career-path.pdf).

You can post questions regarding Cisco certifications over here: [Cisco learning network](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com).